# Is "executive assistant" still much rarer than "secretary"?

Tags: euphemisms, political-correctness, popularity

According to Google NGrams, the term "executive assistant" is much less common than "secretary". Even if I try prefixing both with "his", to avoid meanings such as Secretary-General of the UN, the difference is [still very large](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his%20secretary%2Chis%20executive%20assistant&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20secretary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20executive%20assistant%3B%2Cc0).

Is the term "executive assistant" still much less common than "secretary", when talking about someone who does administrative tasks?

Comment: Personal reflection makes it seem like in 2016, the term 'administrative assistant' is 'what they call it'. Also, consider the date ranges of the search and the corpus.

Comment: I think they refer to  two different roles:  *the difference between a Secretary and a fully-functioning Executive Assistant is that a secretary has a series of tasks they perform and the routine of them becomes easier and easier so they almost don’t have to add much value. The executive assistant has the skills of the secretary PLUS they’re able to anticipate and manipulate the outcomes for improvement.*

Comment: Ngram stops 2008, so you are missing almost a decade of development. Furthermore there are many sorts of assistants besides executive assistant.

Comment: Executive, adminstrative or personal assistant. And there are probably several others to replace secretary. Interesting sign of the times that you add _his_ to filter out unwated results, by the way.

Comment: @oerkelens if you do a ngrams search of "* executive assistant" and "* secretary", "his" is very common, and far more so than "her" or "their".

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I didn't say the trick was not effective, I was just noting that there (still) is a lot of gender bias in who does which job (in this case, it seems that it's predominantly _men_ who have a secretary (or * assistant))

Comment: @oerkelens ok, fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the executive assistant has not made it into dictionaries I'll go with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary#Executive_assistant).

> The work of an executive assistant differs a great deal from that of an administrative assistant. In many organizations, an executive assistant is a high-ranking position in the administrative hierarchy. Executive assistants work for a company officer or executive (at both private and public institutions), and possess the authority to make crucial decisions affecting the direction of such organizations.

&

> A **secretary**, or **personal assistant** is a person whose work consists of supporting management, including executives, using a variety of project management, communication, or organizational skills.

Therefore you are comparing apples and oranges when pairing executive assistant and secretary.

---

I don't know how to link the google books pattern search, so I made screenshots.

Generally the use of assistant seems on the rise in the 2000s:
[image: assistant]

It has even more hits than secretary:
[image: secretary]